# Parsing error: Unexpected token when adding a conditional in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm a beginner in react, I was getting an error for scenarios when no props get passed to my component, it said something like "you can't do a map of undefined" so I added this if statement. But now I get a parsing error on line 4. Not sure' what's wrong with my code:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Record = props => (
  if (props) {
    <div className='card-container'>
      {props.rows.drivingInstructions.map((val, ind) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{ind + 1}</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  }
    { console.log(props.rows.drivingInstructions) }
);
```

Comment: I don't see you actually returning anything from this component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` can't exist in an expression context. For similar reasons, you can't do:

```
const someVar = if (true) 10 else null;
```

The syntax is not permitted. To do something like this, you need the conditional operator:

```
export const Record = props => (
  !props.rows || !props.rows.drivingInstructions ? null : (
    <div className='card-container'>
      {props.rows.drivingInstructions.map((val, ind) => {
        ...
```

Or, if you're OK with the `.card-container` existing even if it doesn't have any rows, use optional chaining instead:

```
export const Record = props => (
  <div className='card-container'>
    {props.rows.drivingInstructions?.map((val, ind) => {
        ...
```

Comment: Oh wow! thank you! I did not know about that rule and technique. The first solution still gave me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" but your second solution worked  that chaining technique is very cool!

Comment: My apologies, the first method also works, I just did not copy it properly ‍♂️

Comment: could you please elaborate on the purpose or meaning of this code? ```!props.rows || !props.rows.drivingInstructions```

Comment: If either of those are falsey, it evaluates to `null`. Otherwise, it evaluates the `.map`

Comment: Done! sorry about that, was unfamiliar with this platform too 

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite those code as below.

```
import React from 'react';

export const Record = (props) => {

  if (!!props?.rows?.drivingInstructions?.length) {

    return (<div className='card-container'>
      {props.rows.drivingInstructions.map((val, ind) =>(
          <tr>
            <td>{ind + 1}</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
        )
      )}
    </div>);
   }

    return <div>No Driving Instructions</div>;
  }
   
};
```

This `!!props?.rows?.drivingInstructions?.length` is an optional chaining and it checks that those properties are not nullish. Lastly, it ensures the length is also more than `0` by converting to boolean using `!!`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

export const Record = props => (
   props?.rows?.drivingInstructions?.length ?
    (<div className='card-container'>
      {props.rows.drivingInstructions.map((val, ind) =>
          <tr>
            <td>{ind + 1}</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
        )}
    </div>) : null;
);
```